# How to add a message in Azure DevOps work item template, "Select a value to field 'XYZ'", without marking that field a mandatory?

Tags: azure-devops, workitem, azure-devops-extensions

How can we notify a user to select a value to a drop-down field in Azure DevOps work item without making it a required field.
The reason of not making it mandatory is because it is not a compulsory information.
But the reason for this 'way to notify' is to make sure that this value is to be filled when it is relevant (which is most of the time - but not all the time).

Comment: Hi @yogesh puttaswamy How was it going with this case， please let me know if there is any question.

Answer (score 0):

There is no option to add a notification on a field without making it mandatory, but there is a workaround to force the user to think about the value of the field.

You can add an additional boolean field who is enabled by default. This field can be used to create a rule for your original field, to indicate if it is required or not.

So to set this up you have to add the following fields/rules to your work item type:

2 fields:

```
originalFieldName (the field with extra attention)
booleanFieldName (Boolean, default value: true)
```

2 Rules:

```
When a work item is created
Then set the value of booleanFieldName to 1

When the value of booleanFieldName Equals 1
Then make originalFieldName required
```

With this solution the user always have to fill in the field or make the field is optional by deselecting the boolean field.

Comment: You can set the default value on the field or if you only want it for one specific work item type you could create a rule. A Rule can be set under: `Organisation -> Process -> <your process> -> <your workitem> -> Rules tab`.

To the REST API, the same rules are applied.

Comment: So I can keep the Boolean field to be 'false' by default and will set it to true after work item is created. By doing this, if there is any application creating a work item using Azure DevOps REST APIs, will continue to create the work item as the field becomes mandatory after work item is created... But if the work item is created and the field is made mandatory, this application using REST APIs will fail during edit flow, if no value for this field is passed.. Correct?

Comment: No, you cannot create the work item via the REST API then, because the rule will be triggered while creating and a work item. (Same as when doing via the GUI)

Answer (score 0):

If you just want a message to be displayed in the work item to notify user to select a value. There is a workaround that you can create a customized process. You can customize the fields and pages in the your custom process.

For testing, i create a custom process and add a notification text to a group name to indicate use to select a value for a field. Please refer to below step.

1, Go to the **Process** section in the **Organization Settings**, and select the process that you want your custom process inherit from. 
[image]

2, Then choose the work item type you want to edit. You can edit or add a fields or group to the work item type. For below example, i edit the title for **Planning** group to add a notification message.

[image]

For more information about custom process please refer the [official documents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/customize-process-field?view=azure-devops).

If you already choose a process to your project. You can refer the detailed steps [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/change-process-basic-to-agile?view=azure-devops) to change your project process to the customized process.

Hope you find above helpful.